# how to send target object in an event to handler function in phaser 3

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework, 2d-games

i'm new in [phaser-3](/questions/tagged/phaser-3) and i have very basic problems in it.
one of my problems is getting target game object(leftArrow) in handler function when i set an [event](/questions/tagged/event).

i tried this code and i can't get target object parameters:

```
leftArrow.customParams = {direction: 1};
leftArrow.setInteractive({pixelPerfect: true});
leftArrow.on('pointerdown', swipe, this);

function swipe(target){

    console.log(target.customParams.direction);

}
```